# Why am I seeing ZombieProcess exceptions when running Python tests with nox on MacOS?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, zombie-process, nox

I'm running Python tests with `nox` for the first time, and although the tests appear to be passing I'm consistently seeing the following (this has nothing to do with `boto3`, it's happening on all my tests with a wide variety of dependencies):

```
======================================================================== 1 passed in 0.01s ========================================================================
nox > Session my_boto3_test(boto3_version='1.22.13') raised exception psutil.ZombieProcess(pid=86804, msg="PID still exists but it's a zombie")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project_path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 343, in wrapper
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/project_path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 401, in cmdline
    return cext.proc_cmdline(self.pid)
ProcessLookupError: [Errno 3] assume no such process (originated from sysctl(KERN_PROCARGS2) -> EINVAL)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project_path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nox/sessions.py", line 695, in execute
    self.func(session)
  File "/project_path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nox/_decorators.py", line 113, in __call__
    return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/project_path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nox/_decorators.py", line 68, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/project_path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nox/_decorators.py", line 68, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/project_path/noxfile.py", line 191, in integration_tests_boto3_sqs
    kill_process_and_clean_outputs(full_path, "run_app", session)
  File "/project_path/noxfile.py", line 647, in kill_process_and_clean_outputs
    kill_process(process_name)
  File "/project_path/noxfile.py", line 657, in kill_process
    if proc.name() == process_name:
  File "/project_path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 628, in name
    cmdline = self.cmdline()
  File "/project_path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 681, in cmdline
    return self._proc.cmdline()
  File "/project_path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 346, in wrapper
    raise ZombieProcess(self.pid, self._name, self._ppid)
psutil.ZombieProcess: PID still exists but it's a zombie (pid=86804)
nox > Session my_boto3_test(boto3_version='1.22.13') failed.
```

I've searched high and low, but I can't find anything documenting this nor a strategy to deal with this, and aside from messing with my OCD I'm not convinced it's even a real problem.

The tests are configured with `noxfile.py` and are running perfectly via GitHub Actions (no warnings or errors, certainly no mentions of any `ZombieProcess`es. I'm running it locally from within a virtualenv, with the command:

`python3 -m nox`

(Same command as the GitHub Actions config uses, all dependencies installed using the same `requirements.txt` and `setup.py`)

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to have nothing to do with `nox` itself, it's a specific call to kill processes using the `psutil` module that I hadn't noticed (yay, other people's code) that doesn't run nicely on Darwin.

The solution (for anyone interested) was wrapping the `proc.kill()` statements in `try` / `except` clauses.